# Do the `length` and `memcmp` filters of `getProgramAccounts()` reduce the scan space?

Tags: performance, getprogramaccounts, scalability

Do they use a linear search or do they have any search indexes in place for the `length` and `memcmp` filters?
Or do they just save us from sending all the accounts over the network, and the CPU usage will be the same regardless?

Comment: it would be helpful to elaborate this question with more details, such as motivation, examples, unexpected observations, etc.  "elaborating" a question with more questions tends to imply a lack of focus and the need for deeper consideration on what the true question should be

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [implementation of `getProgramAccounts`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/e69d8ae7d75703ed2d05d19e3a334b344694416b/rpc/src/rpc.rs#L2031) calls [`load_by_program_with_filter`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/e69d8ae7d75703ed2d05d19e3a334b344694416b/runtime/src/accounts.rs#L900) in the end, which simply does `scan_accounts` with a callback that checks the filter, so the answer is **no, there is no search index for this** in the vanilla solana implementation.

If you need an index for those queries, one possibility is to run your own RPC server with a [geyser plugin](https://docs.solana.com/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins). Geyser plugins allow you to hook into the account storage process to save accounts in additional formats. There is already a plugin for postgres, which may be applicable for this use case: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-accountsdb-plugin-postgres (probably requires quite a lot of resources though).